# android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION returns always -1

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am getting `permsisions` runtime in my android app. I am giving all `permissions` but `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` always returns `-1`. I do not know exactly why it is happenning.

```
private static final String[] permissions = {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};



if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ||checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(permissions,0);
        } else {
           getMyPoints();
        }
    } else {
        getMyPoints();
    }
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    isPermissionDenied = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<grantResults.length ; i++) {
        if(grantResults[i] == -1) {
            isPermissionDenied = true ;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPermissionDenied == true) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Do not put picture of your code. Put code instead.

Comment: you can just remove `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, as you request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Same thing for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, as you request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Thanks it worked.